# How to display storyboard? (iPhone)

Tags: iphone, ios5, uitableview, storyboard, uistoryboard

I've created a storyboard that I want to display using my `UINavigationController`. The initial view in the `storyboard` is a `UITableViewController` so I have created a subclass of `UITableViewController` and set the class on the storyboard to match it.

I then try to display the storyboard like so:

```
StoryBoardView *newView = [[StoryBoardView alloc] init];
[self.navigationController pushViewController:newView animated:YES];
```

However my view is not shown for some reason. Please can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you push the view controller, you need to instantiate the view controller from within your storyboard, not just alloc/init a new instance.

```
StoryBoardView *newView = [[self storyboard] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"<ViewControllerIdentifier>"];
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried when viewing the storyboard, select your very first controller and tick 'Is Initial View Controller'?
That should start your app with that controller.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I just checked and it is already checked.